# why ng-include not working?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

**ng-include not working**

**Directory Structure is as follows :**

```
ssh_project
--public
----templates
------header.html
------footer.html
----views
------index.html
```

**now this is my index.html file**

```
<body>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <div ng-include='"../templates/header.html"'></div>
    <div ng-view></div>
    <div ng-include='"../templates/footer.html"'></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use double quote first then single quote. try below

```
<body>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <div ng-include="'../templates/header.html'"></div>
    <div ng-view></div>
    <div ng-include="'../templates/footer.html'"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just minor mistake.

```
<body>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <div ng-include="'../templates/header.html'"></div>
    <div ng-view></div>
    <div ng-include="'../templates/footer.html'"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

try `<div ng-include="'../templates/header.html'"></div>` because double quotes should be outside and single quotes should be inside. Please change and continue.